# get signalr hub endpoint url in asp.net mvc (where hub is hosted)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have an asp.net mvc 5 web app that hosts my signalr (v2) hub/server. This web app kicks off a console app that needs to connect to the hub. How can I get the full url to my signalr hub from within the web app so that I can pass it as an argument to my console app?

Or is there a better way for my console app to know what the url of the hub is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for is:

```
string hubUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}signalr", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
```

The "signalr" part of the string is the default path to your endpoint. If you changed the default endpoint path, then you need to update that part of the string.